# How to understand memory reference in assembly using ghidra

Tags: c, 64-bit, reverse-engineering, ghidra

When analyzing the assembly listing in Ghidra, the following instructions are not clear to me:

```
MOV    ECX,dword ptr [R13 + 8192]
LEA    RDX,[R13 + RSI*0x1 + 8196]
```

In the MOV, I assume that the register ECX will get the value pointed to the register R13 + 8129 positions (or 2048 bytes). Is this assumption current?

In the LEA, the pointer of the R13 + value of RSI + 8196 position (2049 byte) is assigned to RDX. Is it correct?

Otherwise, how should I interpret those instructions?

Comment: What does your processor's instruction manual say? Is there something that you don't understand from the documentation of the instructions?

Comment: I understand the instructions for x64 processor. My doubts are about the last numbers, i.e., 8192 and 8196, How should I interpret them? Like moving of 2048 and 2049 bytes in the memory?

Comment: Why do you think that a displacement of 8192 (BTW, typo in your question) gives 2048 bytes? Why the divisor of 4?

Comment: Because Ghidra in the decompiling window for the first instruction it says to me something like: `var1= puVar2[2048];`

Comment: You need to look at the element type of that array. Its size is 4, for example `long` or `float`, or so. If you want an extension of my answer for that, please add it to your question. How is `puVar2` declared?

Comment: Ghidra shows me that it is an **int** pointer and the data type is **Integer** 4 bytes

Answer (score -1):

The numbers are called "displacement", they are added to the values left of them.

`mov ecx, dword ptr [r13 + 8192]` adds the value of `r13` and 8192, and copies the 32 bit value at the resulting address into `ecx`.

`lea rdx, [r13 + rsi*0x1 + 8196]` adds the value of `r13`, the result of the multiplication of the value of `rsi` by 1 (giving the value of `rsi`), and 8196, and loads the sum into `rdx`.

These displacements are offsets for the addressable memory units, here bytes. A displacement of 8192 means the byte address 8192 bytes away from the base address.